# CSS Header doesn't fit screen size

Tags: css

I want to have my header fits the size of my screen. Because the background-size is set on "cover" it actually widens automatically, no matter the size of the screen, but the height doesn't fit along. (Sorry for my bad english by the way.) I HAVE to put a height content in the "header td" section, but how do I fix this all? I hope it's clear enough...

CSS:

```
#header-wrap {
    background:url(haderimage.jpg)no-repeat center;
    background-size:cover;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.wsite-custom-background #header-wrap {
    background: none;
}

#header {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#header td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Oh oh, `#header td` you're not doing layout with tables are you?

Comment: Can add some HTML or set up a jsfiddle/codepen please? As soon as this is done, we'll be able to fix the issue. Thanks

Comment: I haven't made the css by myself, but I'm just editing it. I'm not really familiar with coding, css or tables actually.

I don't really know what "header td" does.. :)

Comment: **"I don't really know what "header td" does"**...then, with respect, you're not the person who should be undertaking this task.

Answer (score 0):

You do know HTML5 has a `header` tag built in automatically right?

Anyway, sounds like a margin or padding issue, probably just adding a couple of pixels to the width. Try doing a reset at the top of the css:

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

This can make loading slow sometimes (I've personally never noticed any difference) so if it doesn't help, get rid of it. Otherwise, you could try just hiding the excess width. On your body tag, you could try hiding the overflow. This should stop the page scrolling horizontally but can cause you more width problems later.

```
body{
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean adding the margin and padding in one of the header sections? Like header-wrap?

Comment: I don't think this will solve much of @user3759898 issues. This solution fixes horizontal problems, but he/she is having trouble with the height not the width.

Comment: Yep that's correct. All I can do now to solve the problem is to maximize the height in the "header td" section, but when viewing on a bigger screen, the header is cut off to that pixel size.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I thought you were having horizontal issues when you said `it actually widens automatically`. @user3759898, please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or similar including the HTML and CSS to show us the problem.

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to find the html part, but here is the css:
http://jsfiddle.net/Noukster/VsQE6/
The CSS is based on a basic website from Weebly.com, where you can create a free website.